# Call sp with parameter without user input from Crystal Reports Developer

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports, parameter-passing, crystal-reports-xi

I am using Crystal Reports Developer version 11 (XI).
I am using a stored procedure that accepts a parameter. The problem is that I have to repeatedly call the procedure for a series of subreports, each with a different parameter. And I don't want the user to have to input the parameters each time the run the report because there are so many. I want the parameter to static and stored in the report.

But I cannot see how I can do this. Is it even possible? How can I do this?
The parameter options in Field Explorer appear to be just for filtering after the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a default value for the parameter solves the problem.